# Amount of times each JSON field is repeated in array php

Tags: php, json, sorting, field

I am wanting to get some code to get a list of each unique client ID and how often that client ID is repeated through the array.

Below is a snippet of the JSON.

What I would like is something like the following please in PHP if possible.

```
Mac 12:12:12:12:12 20 times
Mac 23:23:23:23:23 15 times
Mac 34:34:34:34:34 2 times
```

Is there an easy way to do this please?

Thanks.

Rob

```
"ranges": [
    {
      "clients": [
        {
          "clientId": {
            "mac": "86:8f:c2:8f:c3:20"
          },
          "rssis": [
            {
              "sourceId": "zR1L3",
              "value": -90.4
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "clientId": {
            "mac": "6c:19:8f:bf:47:e9"
          },
          "rssis": [
            {
              "sourceId": "zR1L3",
              "value": -91.3
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "clientId": {
            "mac": "58:6d:8f:75:95:0e"
          },
          "rssis": [
            {
              "sourceId": "zR1L3",
              "value": -86.3
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "clientId": {
            "mac": "68:72:51:10:e7:26"
          },
          "rssis": [
            {
              "sourceId": "zR1L3",
              "value": -53.7
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "clientId": {
            "mac": "38:2c:4a:5c:b6:a0"
          },
          "rssis": [
            {
              "sourceId": "zR1L3",
              "value": -87.1
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "clientId": {
            "mac": "68:72:51:10:e7:29"
          },
          "rssis": [
            {
              "sourceId": "zR1L3",
              "value": -76.9
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "clientId": {
            "uniqueId": "CQos"
          },
          "rssis": [
            {
              "sourceId": "zR1L3",
              "value": -70.2
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "clientId": {
            "mac": "a4:ee:57:2e:ac:bd"
          },
          "rssis": [
            {
              "sourceId": "zR1L3",
              "value": -95
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "clientId": {
            "uniqueId": "ECgg"
          },
          "rssis": [
            {
              "sourceId": "zR1L3",
              "value": -75.4
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "clientId": {
            "mac": "58:6d:8f:74:bf:f9"
          },
          "rssis": [
            {
              "sourceId": "zR1L3",
              "value": -70
            }
          ]
        }
      ],
      "timestamp": "2015-11-09T22:06:00+00:00"
    },
    {
      "clients": [
        {
          "clientId": {
            "mac": "86:8f:c2:8f:c3:20"
          },
          "rssis": [
            {
              "sourceId": "zR1L3",
              "value": -93
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "clientId": {
            "mac": "6c:19:8f:bf:47:e9"
          },
          "rssis": [
            {
              "sourceId": "zR1L3",
              "value": -90.8
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "clientId": {
            "mac": "58:6d:8f:75:95:0e"
          },
          "rssis": [
            {
              "sourceId": "zR1L3",
              "value": -87.2
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "clientId": {
            "mac": "68:72:51:10:e7:26"
          },
          "rssis": [
            {
              "sourceId": "zR1L3",
              "value": -54.1
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "clientId": {
            "mac": "38:2c:4a:5c:b6:a0"
          },
          "rssis": [
            {
              "sourceId": "zR1L3",
              "value": -87
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "clientId": {
            "mac": "68:72:51:10:e7:29"
          },
          "rssis": [
            {
              "sourceId": "zR1L3",
              "value": -77.2
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "clientId": {
            "uniqueId": "CQos"
          },
          "rssis": [
            {
              "sourceId": "zR1L3",
              "value": -70.8
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "clientId": {
            "mac": "a4:ee:57:2e:ac:bd"
          },
          "rssis": [
            {
              "sourceId": "zR1L3",
              "value": -95
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "clientId": {
            "uniqueId": "ECgg"
          },
          "rssis": [
            {
              "sourceId": "zR1L3",
              "value": -72.8
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "clientId": {
            "mac": "58:6d:8f:74:bf:f9"
          },
          "rssis": [
            {
              "sourceId": "zR1L3",
              "value": -70
            }
          ]
        }
      ],
      "timestamp": "2015-11-09T22:07:00+00:00"
    },
```

Comment: You should clarify your question. Do you want the mac address? Just the count? Only the unique ones? All of them? You want PHP to handle this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First loop through the json and build an array of mac addresses:

```
$data = json_decode($json, true);
$macs = array();

foreach ($data['ranges'] as $range) {
    foreach ($range['clients'] as $client) {
        // check if the client has a mac address, and add it to the array
        if (isset($client['clientId']['mac'])) {
            $macs[] = $client['clientId']['mac'];
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can simply use [`array_count_values`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php):

`var_dump(array_count_values($macs));`

This will output an array with the mac address as the key, and the frequency as the value:

```
array (size=8)
  '86:8f:c2:8f:c3:20' => int 2
  '6c:19:8f:bf:47:e9' => int 2
  '58:6d:8f:75:95:0e' => int 2
  '68:72:51:10:e7:26' => int 2
  '38:2c:4a:5c:b6:a0' => int 2
  '68:72:51:10:e7:29' => int 2
  'a4:ee:57:2e:ac:bd' => int 2
  '58:6d:8f:74:bf:f9' => int 2
```

So you can just do

```
foreach (array_count_values($macs) as $mac => $frequency)
{
    echo "Mac {$mac} {$frequency} times<br/>";
}
```

There are other ways, for example in the loop you could check if the mac has been seen already, and just add 1 to a count as you go along. But this way seems simplest.

Comment: Brilliant. Thanks @rjdown so much. Worked perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure about an easy way, but you can iterate over the data and store your findings in an array.

```
//parse json
$data = json_decode( $json );

//store mac addresses
$parsed = array();

foreach( $data['ranges'] as $range ) {
    foreach( $range->clients as $client ) {
        $address = $client->clientId->mac;

        if( ! isset( $parsed[$address] ) )
            $parsed[$address] = 0;

        $parsed[$address]++;
    }
}

//output as requested
foreach( $parsed as $mac => $count )
    echo "Mac {$mac} {$count} <br />";
```

Comment: Very nice. Is `if( ! isset( $parsed[$address] ) ) $parsed[$address] = 0; $parsed[$address]++;` equivalent to `$parsed[$address] = ++$parsed[$address] || 0;` ?

Comment: @SalvoF no, it will generate an undefined index notice, and set the value to true...